# Creating a Flutter Alert/Dialog Without Context

Tags: flutter, dialog, android-context, synchronous, navigator

I currently have a Flutter app which keeps track of the amount of time a user spends on the app with a timer which runs in the background. Users can set limits on the amount of time they spend in the app. Every minute, the timers checks if the user has exceeded their time limit. If so, I want to display a dialog or alert telling the user this.

The problem is that the timer has no way to access the current context and thus no way to create my dialog. Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a package that enables you show dialogs with no need BuildContext from business layer. It's called OneContext.

That package also works with page navigation, overlays and other things with no need BuildContext.

Take a look at: https://pub.dev/packages/one_context

Use example:

```dart
// example dialog
OneContext().showDialog(
    // barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (_) => AlertDialog( 
        title: new Text("The Title"),
        content: new Text("The Body"),
    )
);
```

```dart
// example snackBar
OneContext().showSnackBar(
    builder: (_) => SnackBar(content: Text('My awesome snackBar!'))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by creating a custom Dialog Manager and a locator.

You can read the full tutorial here : https://medium.com/flutter-community/manager-your-flutter-dialogs-with-a-dialog-manager-1e862529523a

Answer (score 0):

There is a package for it called [Stacked_services](https://pub.dev/packages/stacked_services)

It provides: `NavigationService`, `DialogService` and `SnackbarService`.